# String index out of range in jva

Tags: java, string, methods, char, boolean

> A string is a palindrome if it is spelled the same way backward and
>   forward.
>
> Examples of palindromes include “Radar” and “Dammit, I’m mad!”.
>
> Write a java program, PalindromeTester, that asks the user to enter a
>   word or sentence and then checks whether the entered string is a
>   palindrome or not.
>
> Spaces, nonalphabetics (.,!:?-()\";), and case within the string have
>   to be ignored e.g., "Drab as a fool, aloof as a bard." is a
>   palindrome.
>
> Your implementation should define and use the method isPalindrome to
>   test if a certain string is a palindrome. The signature of the
>   isPalindrome method is as follows:
>
> ```
> boolean isPalindrome(String)
> ```
>
> Following is a sample run of the program. The user’s input is shown in bold.
>
> ```
> java PalindromeTester
> Introduction to Computer Programming (CMPS 200)
> Spring 2015-16 2 of 3
> Enter a string: I love CMPS 200
> The string "I love CMPS 200" is NOT a palindrome.
> ```

This is the code I made, it keeps giving me an error.

**I would like to know  what my error is and whether there's a faster easier way of writing this code**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PalindromeTester {
    public static void main (String args []) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
        String palindrome = console.next();
        if (isPalindrome (palindrome)) {
            System.out.print("The string \""+palindrome+" is a palindrome.");
        } else {
            System.out.print("The string \""+palindrome+" is NOT a palindrome.");
        }
    }

    public static boolean  isPalindrome (String palindrome) {
        int constant = 1;
        for (int i = 0 ; i <= (palindrome.length()-1) ; i++) {
            for (int z= (palindrome.length()-1);i >= 0; i--) {
                if (palindrome.charAt(i) <'@'||'Z'<palindrome.charAt(i)&&palindrome.charAt(i)<'`'||'['<palindrome.charAt(i)&&palindrome.charAt(i)<'{') {
                    i=i+1; 
                }
                if (palindrome.charAt(z)<'@'||'Z'<palindrome.charAt(z)&&palindrome.charAt(z)<'`'||'['<palindrome.charAt(z)&&palindrome.charAt(z)<'{') {
                    z=z+1;
                }
                if (palindrome.charAt(i)==(palindrome.charAt(z))) {
                    constant = constant * 1;
                } else {
                    constant = constant * 0;
                } 
            }
        }
        if (constant == 0 ) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Please show the error you are getting.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 7
 at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
 at PalindromeTester.isPalindrome(PalindromeTester.java:23)
 at PalindromeTester.main(PalindromeTester.java:8)
is the error i get

Answer (score 0):

Index out of range is caused by `palindrome.charAt(z))` after `z = z + 1;`

Keep simple :

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String palindrome)
{
    palindrome = palindrome.replaceAll("\\W", ""); // remove all non word character
    palindrome = palindrome.toLowerCase();
    int size = palindrome.length();
    int halfSize = size / 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < halfSize; i++)
    {
        if(palindrome.charAt(i) != palindrome.charAt(size - i - 1))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Your `halfsize` variable stores half of the length of the string, but your loop only goes halfway down this amount - so you are only checking 1/4 of the string. Also, you are not handling the punctuation and whitespace characters that need to be ignored.

Comment: The loop will check the first half and the last half in the same time. Why 1/4 ?

Comment: Because your loop stops at `halfSize / 2`.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to strip the non alpha characters out of the string. Then check if the string is the same as itself reversed (while upper case):

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String palindrome) {
    StringBuilder sanitisedString = new StringBuilder();
    for(char c : palindrome.toCharArray()) {
        if(Character.isLetter(c)) {
            sanitisedString.append(c);
        }
    }
    return sanitisedString.toString().toUpperCase().equals(sanitisedString.reverse().toString().toUpperCase());
}
```

Comment: I had considered that, but removed it. So I have added it back in.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make a new String and save the reversed source(String) in it.

```
public static boolean readstring(String s)
{
    String b = "";
    for (int i= s.length() -1; i >=0 ;i--)
    {
        b = b + s.charAt(i);
    }
    System.out.print(b +" and "+ s +"    ");
    return b == s || b.Equals(s);
}
```

EDIT: Hopefully this meets the requirements, by the way dont use the word "ignore" but "allow"

Comment: Your code returns false if there are any punctuation or whitespace characters. This does not meet the requirement. Your code should ignore punctuation and whitespace while deciding if the string is a palindrome.

Comment: Yep, read it again and you were right, changed the code above but im not sure if it still meets the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public boolean isPalindrome(String word) {
        int backward = word.length() - 1;
        for (int x = 0; x < word.length(); x++) {
            if (word.charAt(x)!= word.charAt(backward--)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, however it would be better to add an explanation of your code and why it would a better answer and worth some votes. It would help others learn from you!